# Javascript "click" not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, click

I am developing a script to do some maintenance on my web page, and not have to do it manually.
I am using the following script:

```
var fechas = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var num = fechas.length/9;
var textofinal = "";
for(var i = 0; i<num; i++) {    
    var fechaBase = fechas[(i*9)+7].innerText;
    console.log(i);
    if(!(fechaBase == "Sin picks" || document.getElementsByTagName("td")[(i*9)+2].firstElementChild.className == "el-switch is-checked" || document.getElementsByTagName("td")[(i*9)+3].firstElementChild.className != "el-switch is-checked")) {
        console.log(i);
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de enero, ", "/1/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de febrero, ", "/2/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de marzo, ", "/3/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de abril, ", "/4/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de mayo, ", "/5/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de junio, ", "/6/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de julio, ", "/7/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de agosto, ", "/8/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de septiembre, ", "/9/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de octubre, ", "/10/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de noviembre, ", "/11/");
        fechaBase = fechaBase.replace(" de diciembre, ", "/12/");
        textofinal = textofinal + " " + fechaBase;
        var dateParts = fechaBase.split("/");
        var then = new Date(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]); 
        now  = new Date().getTime(),
        thirtyDaysInMilliseconds = 2592000000;
        if (now - then > thirtyDaysInMilliseconds) { 
            console.log("i es " + i + " y num es " + num);
            sleep(3000);
            var tdd = (i*9)+3;
            console.log("primer td " + tdd);
            document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[(i+1)].click();             
            sleep(3000);
            console.log("segundo td " + tdd);
            document.getElementsByClassName("el-switch__core")[2].click();          
            sleep(3000);
            console.log("tercer td " + tdd);
            document.getElementsByClassName("w-btn-outline")[0].click();            
            sleep(3000);
        }
        
    }
}
function sleep(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

The script goes through a series of elements row by row, performs some checks and clicks on those that need to be reviewed, browsing the web, or at least that is the goal. The problem is this lines:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[(i+1)].click();             
document.getElementsByClassName("el-switch__core")[2].click();          
document.getElementsByClassName("w-btn-outline")[0].click();
```

If I execute them separately, they open the element, check a box inside and return back to the list, but in the whole code is not working, it only opens the last item in the list when the task ends. Any ideas? Thanks.

NOTES:

- The code reaches the click steps, but they are not working, the clicks are not fired. They only get fired if I execute them separately.
- If I make it async:

setTimeout(() => {document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[column].click();}, (i+5)*1000);

it works, but not in the order I want to be executed.

Comment: can you try replacing var with let in for loop?

Comment: @ShyamKumar all vars for lets? Or which? Thanks!

Comment: just the for loop variable

Comment: @ShyamKumar it still not working :(